# IDEA cannot import java class from package if package conflcts with groovy package

Tags: java, intellij-idea, groovy

So I have a groovy project with some java classes in IntelliJ IDEA.
Both java and groovy directory are the source directories.

Directory structure as below -

```
src / generated / java / com / companyName / config / Class1.java

src / main / groovy /com / companyName / config /Class2.groovy
```

I am writing another class in groovy source directory

```
src / main / groovy / com / companyName / core / Class3.groovy

import com.companyName.config.Class1
public class Class3 {
}
```

Seems like IntelliJ IDEA cannot resolve the Class1.java file and it tries to search in the groovy source directory as it can find the same path in the groovy source directory.

Is there any way I can make IDEA to search in the java source directory for the Class that I want to import

Comment: Can you show us a snapshot of your project structure?

Comment: If your Java and Groovy code be in separate modules, then you can simply add the Java module as a dependency for the Groovy module, q.v. [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html#add_module_dependency).  This should fix the import errors in IntelliJ.  As to whether your external build will pass, this is another story.

Comment: Is the generated directory marked as a source directory?

Comment: So i just found out in the project that the java class is generated by  QueryDSL (http://www.querydsl.com/) when I run that app. I am new to the project and hence reading up further on the QueryDSL. I think IDEA is not liking it and it should confuse IDEA since the classes are generated on the fly (thats what I think)